# ASUS - unable to use USB because Win7 doesn't recognise the USB Controller

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, asus-laptop

So, I just reinstalled Windows on my [ASUS K55VD laptop](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/K55VD/), and installed all the drivers I could find from the ASUS Support website, but I'm still unable to use USB devices (anything I connect, flash drive, mouse, anything, Windows doesn't detect it)

[image: Device Manager]

[image: Driver Installer]

I have only the drivers installed (none of the utilities, except the ATKACPI driver, which is in the utilities category for some reason).

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you provide the model number of your laptop someone may be able to help.

Comment: Double check both "AsMedia USB3.0 Driver" and "Intel INF Update Driver" are installed.

Comment: @davidbaumann I can confirm both have been installed, and I have just reinstalled them. No change.

Comment: Get the hardware id and search for it: http://666kb.com/i/bf6f4y37gzztjbaf9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the driver download website, USB category, you can see that there's AsMedia USB3.0 download.

Since you said you have already installed that, it seems you don't have the AsMedia XHCI controller, but the alternative, Intel XHCI controller.
To get a download for that one, you need to click the "Show all downloads" link right under the AsMedia driver.

In other words, installing the Intel USB3.0 driver, instead of the AsMedia one, should fix your problem.